# Making a function continuous by choosing a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have no idea how to solve when $k$ isn't in the second equation.

> $$
> y=f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 2x^3+x^2-3 & \text{ if } x<-1\\ 
> -\sqrt{x+k} & \text{ if }x \ge -1
> \end{cases}
> $$

Find the value of $k$ that makes this function continuous for $x=-1$.

Comment: One useful thing would be to substitute $x=-1$ in both branches of the function and see if any ideas come up afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this function is continuous for $x=-1$, then the two equations have the same value when $x=-1$. 
For the first equation, it has no definition at $-1$, so we take the limit from left:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow (-1)^-}2x^3+x^2-3=-4,$$ then we need the second equation equals $-4$ when $x=-1$, so we have
$$-\sqrt{x+k}=-4|_{x=-1}$$
$$\Rightarrow-\sqrt{-1+k}=-4$$
$$\Rightarrow k=17$$

Comment: This was a homework question and you just gave the full answer. Why not just give a hint?

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$ is continuous at $a$ if
$$
\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x) = \lim_{x\to a^+} f(x) = f(a).
$$
So you need to find the value of $k$ such that 
$$
\lim_{x\to (-1)^{-}}f(x) = \lim_{x\to (-1)^+} f(x) = f(-1).
$$
Note that $f(-1) = -\sqrt{-1 + k}$. So all that is left for you to do is to find the limits.